# c# winform vs 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm new at c# winform. I added a picture box then put a picture then it showed like I wanted to. Then I added another picture box then added another picture. Then this showed. After I clicked OK, this showed

There is already a command handler for the menu command '5efc7975-14bc-11cf-9b2b-00aa00573819 : 26'.        0   0

Could anybody help?

Comment: Use Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings.

Comment: There is no reason to use vs2012 as a new C# developer. You can get vs2017 Community edition for free from the visual studio website.